# syntax error near unexpected token `(' When running custom detector on an image on COLAB, all my files save on google drive

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, yolov4, gdrive

I am trying to Run custom detector on an image with this command. (The thresh flag sets the minimum accuracy required for object detection) on COLAB, all my files save on google drive.

'
!./darknet detector test data/obj.data cfg/yolov4-custom.cfg /content/drive/MyDrive/yolov4_darknet/training/yolov4-custom_best.weights /content/drive/MyDrive/yolov4_darknet/vehicle_test_images/20220421_103809.jpg -thresh 0.3 imShow('predictions.jpg')
'

The problem is that I am getting a syntax error message saying

'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `(' /bin/bash: -c: line 0:` ./darknet detector test data/obj.data cfg/yolov4-custom.cfg /content/drive/MyDrive/yolov4_darknet/training/yolov4-custom_best.weights /content/drive/MyDrive/yolov4_darknet/vehicle_test_images/20220421_103809.jpg -thresh 0.3 imShow('predictions.jpg')'
'

How do i fix the problem?

Comment: The `imShow('predictions.jpg')` part doesn't fit with the rest - that's something that might go in a Python script, not a shell command line.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.